# Assigning boolean value to column's values which starts with numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

```
    Name              Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7
    tfedup.sm           1   1   1   1   1   1   1
    13wham.cc           1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
    1chancerslane.cc    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
    24layover.cc        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
    301-joy.cycle.cc    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I would like to create a new column saying if a name starts with a number. I did

```
# Starts with numbers

    df['Nane_num'] = list( 
        map(lambda x: x.isdigit(), df['Name']))
```

but it gives me only False values.What is wrong in my code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) with first value of string by `str[0]`:

```
df['Nane_num'] = df['Name'].str[0].str.isdigit()
print (df)
               Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Nane_num
0         tfedup.sm     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     False
1         13wham.cc     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      True
2  1chancerslane.cc     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      True
3      24layover.cc     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      True
4  301-joy.cycle.cc     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `x[0].isdigit()`, because x is the entire name.
Doing `x.isdigit()` will check is the whole name is composed with digit.

```py
df['Nane_num'] = list(map(lambda x: x[0].isdigit(), df['Name']))
```

This is not the best way to achieve your goal, the solution from jezrael is better.